# Fragment is not restored after app process is killed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have an activity with recyclerview. In recyclerview's adapter, when user clicks on element, a new Fragment is created. The problem is that when I press home button, kill app process and then restore app, the fragment is not recreated. How could I restore fragment after app process is killed?

EDIT:

My onCreate method in activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;

        rvMain = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvMain);
        rvMain.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(numbers, context);
        rvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

onBindViewHolder method in recyclerview adapter where fragment is called:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Number number = numbers.get(position);

        holder.lytMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DetailedFragment fragment = new DetailedFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("message", number.getName());
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                ((MainActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack("fragment")
                        .replace(R.id.lytDetailed, fragment)
                        .commit();

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @YusufÇağlar added some code

Comment: addToBackStack make the job for me

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I moved calling a fragment to a method inside MainActivity and then I save fragment instance with onSaveInstanceState and restore it with onRestoreInstanceState. Here is how it looks.

onBindViewHolder in adapter:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Number number = numbers.get(position);

        holder.lytMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity)context).getFragment(number);
            }
        });
    }
```

getFragment() method in MainActivity:

```
    public void getFragment(Number number){
        fragment = new DetailedFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("message", number.getName());
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack("fragment")
                .replace(R.id.lytDetailed, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState:

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "detailed_fragment", fragment);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(outState);
            fragment = (DetailedFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .getFragment(outState, "detailed_fragment");

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack("fragment")
                    .replace(R.id.lytDetailed, fragment)
                    .commit();
    }
```